# Filter object values based on array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have two variables, one is an object of POST data (two checkboxes, and an email input):

```
{ _csrf: 'oWNyWOhgvRyEGafTTOO1Yiv78BfG0D1n+DLVA=',
  activated: 'true',
  notify: 'true',
  email: 'test@gmail.com' }
```

Another, is a configuration template file, which is used to generate the form (where the POST data comes from):

```
[{ displayName: 'Activated',
  name: 'activated',
  description: '',
  type: 'Boolean',
  defaults: { value: false, readOnly: false } }
{ displayName: 'Send Notifications',
  name: 'notify',
  description: '',
  type: 'Boolean',
  defaults: { value: false, readOnly: false } }
{ displayName: 'Notification Email',
  name: 'email',
  description: '',
  type: 'String:Email',
  defaults: { value: '', readOnly: false } }]
```

I need filter the first object down to `key: value` pairs where the key is present in the array (`name: 'key'`).

I'm trying to use `_.filter` and `_.find`, however what I have written so far successfully filters the object, but only returns an array of the values, without keys:

```
const update = _.filter(req.body, function(val, name){
  return _.find(_module.config, function(param){
    return param.name == name;
  });
});

// update = [ 'true', 'true', 'test@gmail.com' ]
```

Finally, my last issue is that if one of the checkboxes isn't checked, no value for that key is present in the POST data. Ideally, the filter function should also set any values it finds in the configuration template but not in the data to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`.reduce()` the array and take from the original object just the properties that match the items' names:

```js
function filterPropsByArray(arr, obj) {
  return arr.reduce(function(o, item) {
    obj.hasOwnProperty(item.name) && (o[item.name] = obj[item.name]); // if the name exists in the original object, assign it
    return o;
  }, {});
} 

var obj = { _csrf: 'oWNyWOhgvRyEGafTTOO1Yiv78BfG0D1n+DLVA=',
  activated: 'true',
  notify: 'true',
  email: 'test@gmail.com' };

var arr = [{ displayName: 'Activated',
  name: 'activated',
  description: '',
  type: 'Boolean',
  defaults: { value: false, readOnly: false } },
{ displayName: 'Send Notifications',
  name: 'notify',
  description: '',
  type: 'Boolean',
  defaults: { value: false, readOnly: false } },
{ displayName: 'Notification Email',
  name: 'email',
  description: '',
  type: 'String:Email',
  defaults: { value: '', readOnly: false } }];

var result = filterPropsByArray(arr, obj); 

console.log(result);
```